# Wierd output when trying to push an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have written the below code I am getting the output as `cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

```
var data = [
            { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-OCT-14|0.59" },
            { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-OCT-14|0.87" },
            { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
            { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-NOV-14|0.67" },
            { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
            { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-DEC-14|0.03" }
           ];
var cmname  = new Array();
var cmdate  = new Array();
var crank   = [];
var mktshare = new Array(); 
for(i=0;i<data.length; i++ ){
    var name = data[i].MFG_NAME;
    for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){   
        mkt_share = new Array();
        cdate = new Array();
        if(name=data[j].MFG_NAME)
        {
            cmsk_data = data[j].CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split('|');
            cdate[j].push(cmsk_data[0]) ;  //Here I am getting the error
            mkt_share[j].push(cmsk_data[1]) ; //Here I am getting the error
        }
    }
    cmdate[i] = cdate;      
    mktshare[i] = mkt_share;
        alert(cdate);
}
cmname[i] = name;
```

Then I have changed it to the below code. It is giving a wierd output in the alert

```
  var data = new Array();
data = <?php echo $result; ?>;  
var dlen    = data.length;
var cmname  = new Array();
var cmdate  = new Array();
var crank   = [];
var mktshare = new Array(); 
for(i=0;i<data.length; i++ ){
    var name = data[i].MFG_NAME;
    for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){   
        mkt_share = new Array();
        cdate = new Array();
        if(name=data[j].MFG_NAME)
        {
            cmsk_data = data[j].CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split('|');
            cdate[j] = cmsk_data[0] ;
            mkt_share[j] = cmsk_data[1] ;
        }
    }
    cmdate[i] = cdate;      
    mktshare[i] = mkt_share;
     alert(cdate);
}
cmname[i] = name; alert(cmname);
```

I am getting the below output in alert `alert(cdate)` in the loop

[image]

Why I am getting this output instead the output in alert must be `01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14`

Also the alert `alert(cmname)` is giving the same kind of output as below

[image]

Instead in the alert the output must be `ABC,XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are attempting to push to items within the array that do not exist; `cdate[j]` and `mkt_share[j]` respectively. The `push()` method is only available on array types, as such you should call it on `cdate` anf `mkt_share` without the indexer:

```
cdate.push(cmsk_data[0]);
mkt_share.push(cmsk_data[1]);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jupr8cwq/)

Comment: what should I do to get the output cmdate[0] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] , cmdate[1] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] and mkt_share[0] = [0.59,0.25,0.1] and mkt_share[1] = [0.87,0.67,0.03] and cmname = [ABC,XYZ]

Answer (score 0):

You get the error in

```
cdate[j].push(cmsk_data[0]) ;
```

because `cdate[j]` is undefined.

Comment: what should I do to get the output cmdate[0] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] , cmdate[1] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] and mkt_share[0] = [0.59,0.25,0.1] and mkt_share[1] = [0.87,0.67,0.03] and cmname = [ABC,XYZ]

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to read back element `j` in the cdate array and then `push` a new object into the array.  To add new elements you use the array name directly as shown below.

```
cdate.push(cmsk_date[0]);
```

You can also perform a check at any point to ensure that the array is defined:

```
if (cdate != undefined) {
   cdate.push(cmsk_data[0]) ;
}
```

Also, you have a few issues with your code:

```
 if(name=data[j].MFG_NAME)
        {
            cmsk_data = data[j].CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split('|');
            cdate[j].push(cmsk_data[0]) ;  //Here I am getting the error
            mkt_share[j].push(cmsk_data[1]) ; //Here I am getting the error
        }
```

You are assigning `name` in your conditional statement, not comparing, you should use `==` or `===`.  For example:

```
if (name == data[j].MFG_NAME) { }
```

Also you are creating two new arrays for each iteration in the for loop:

```
for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){   
        mkt_share = new Array();
        cdate = new Array();
}
```

If `data` had a length of 1,000 it would create 2,000 arrays and eat up memory on the client's browser.

Comment: Do I have to clear the array every time or what should I do to get the output cmdate[0] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] , cmdate[1] = [01-OCT-14,01-NOV-14,01-DEC-14] and mkt_share[0] = [0.59,0.25,0.1] and mkt_share[1] = [0.87,0.67,0.03] and cmname = [ABC,XYZ]